# Can we call website / product images through IP address, instead of domain name - will it be better?

Tags: php

I compared my Ecommerce website /product images calling from both IP address and domain name and I found that It is faster when using IP address.

So can we used IP address for calling website static images OR product images?

It is fine , when site is on https , we can use domain name else IP address.

What are the drawbacks using IP address - regarding SEO wise etc?

What about images site map.

Any other suggestion to call and load images faster?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Kamlesh

Comment: Can you define *faster*? It should **not** be significantly faster; as in: not at all save for the first DNS request. Is your server having trouble resolving the host somehow? Does it handles the IP access differently from the hostname access.

Comment: Yes I checked in different speed test tool and it was faster to load for sure.  logically also it should be faster, as http request will not have to resolve host name.

Comment: You really only resolve the host name with the first request, which has (usually) already been made when you enter the web site.

Comment: DNS requests are cached and should at most be a one-time overhead. If DNS lookups are significant on *every HTTP request* your local DNS is busted or your main DNS is configured incorrectly.

Comment: Use http://yslow.org/ to gather intel on what might be the bottleneck. It gives solid advice.

Answer (score 0):

Domain names are a flexible mapping between a human readable name and a physical IP address. It's useful to have this additional layer of flexibility. You may want to or may have to change IP addresses eventually; you may want to load-balance your site somehow someday and will have to divert to different IP addresses... there are *many* reasons for using a domain name. The only reasons for using the bare IP address are:

- no DNS lookup; but this should be a **minimal overhead on the first request**, it should by no means be significantly faster
- you don't have to purchase and maintain a domain name; but I suppose you have one already, so this is moot

IMO the reasons for domain names far outweigh the reasons for IPs.

Having said that, ideally you wouldn't hardcode domains names at all and simply use relative links, e.g. `<img src="/img/foo.jpg">`, instead of `<img src="http://foo.bar/baz.jpg">`, and most certainly not `<img src="http://1.2.3.4/baz.jpg">`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am the developer - so no issue about domain name purchase. Many of website does not have load balancing - so we can use in that case - but as  per your comment if overhead is on the first request mainly - then it should be fine - I have to check again - as all the speed test tool score for first request only - I found significant difference. - but not sure about relative path has any role in speed.

Comment: Relative paths have *no* impact on performance, only on the *flexibility* of your code.

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately , we keep having many images in website - which causes lots of request - and hence speed issue. - I know about cdn, keep alive, sprite images - but there are many limitation - as such we can not call images faster without http request.